# outputting only if diff has something

Tags: python, linux, diff

I am writing a python script to do some stuff and then in the end i do a diff of two files and write it to a file. This is done for like 100 files, and i am getting 100 outputs and most of them are empty. I want to write the output only if the diff has some output. I am doing something like this

```
    subprocess.Popen("diff -c -p sample1"+i+".txt sample"+i+".txt > output"+1+".txt",shell=True)
```

This creates a lot of empty output*.txt files.I want the output only if there is a diff. Is there some option i am missing.

Comment: You can use filecmp module

    `import filecmp;
    filecmp.cmpfiles('filename1', 'filename2')`


filecmp.cmpfiles will return true or false true if both the files are same and false if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Intead of excuting the external diff command I would recommend using a library such as [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html). That would allow you to decide when, or when not, to output the diff. The subshell spawned by Popen will always create a file since you are using redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a bash question, not a Python question - though see also Fred Clausen's answer on how to turn it into a Python question ;-)

There are some answers in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/210054/make-a-pipe-conditional-on-non-empty-return) on SuperUser - in summary, some possibilities are:

- Create a bash script that detects empty input, and call that from python
- Use the [ifne](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/ifne.1.html) command (runs the following command if and only if stdin is not empty)
- use `xargs -r` to swallow empty input

Answer (score 0):

*Popen* creates a process object - which you may *communicate()* (process object method!) to. Add *stdout=subrpocess.PIPE* to Popen call, and remove output redirection.
Or you may just use subprocess.check_output()